# ¿Como convertir un String en una lista json en java?

Tags: java, json, soap, gson

Tengo dos campos tipo String que se mandan en el request de un servicio SOAP, uno es **NumPersona** y el otro es **ListMuestra** en este ùltimo campo me mandaran algo como esto

```
{
    "listPruebas": [
        {
            "nombrePrueba": "prueba1",
            "idPrueba": 0,
            "tipoPrueba": "12",
            "elemento": "123",
            "listaMarca": [
                {
                    "elemento": "elemento1 ",
                    "tipo": "tipo1",
                    "cadena": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAI"
                },
                {
                    "elemento": "elemento2",
                    " tipo ": "tipo2",
                    " cadena ": " iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAMAAADDM"
                },
                {
                    "elemento": "elemento3",
                    " tipo ": "tipo3",
                    " cadena ": " iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAMAAADDpiT"
                },
                {
                    "elemento": "elemnto4",
                    " tipo ": "tipo4",
                    " cadena ": " iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAMAAADDpiTIAAA"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "nombrePrueba": "prueba2",
            "idPrueba": 3,
            "tipoPrueba": "fija",
            "elemento": "sdc34",
            "listaMarca2": [
                {
                    "elemento": "elemento5",
                    "tipo": "tipo5",
                    "cadena": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAA"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "listaBuscar": [
        {
            "tipoBusqueda": "busqueda1",
            "id": 1,
            "operacion": "operacion1",
            "valor": "12"
        },
        {
            "tipoBusqueda": "binario",
            "id": 2,
            "operacion": "operacion2",
            "valor": "13"
        },
        {
            "tipoFiltro": "numerico",
            "id": 31,
            "operacion": "MENOR_QUE",
            "valor": "1980",
            "intervalo": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Como le hago para yo recibir en esa estructura json lo que me mandan en el campo String **ListMuestra**?
No tengo idea, que puedo utilizar?

Comment: necesitas usar gson?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que te estoy entendiendo, para lo que quieres hacer te deberías crear un objeto con las variables que busques almacenar. Luego con Gson, parsea el JSON que estas recibiendo y mapea los valores.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

String json = "{ \"f1\":\"Hello\",\"f2\":{\"f3:\":\"World\"}}";

JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(json);

JsonObject jsonObject = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();

JsonElement f1 = jsonObject.get("f1");

JsonElement f2 = jsonObject.get("f1");
```

Espero que te sirva.